# Cannot resolve symbol of the compressed image file - android firebase image upload

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to load an image into Firebase memory and convert it to a maximum bitmap height and width of `1200`. But when I try to send the bitmap image of the converted image to the upload operation, it says `Unable to resolve the 'selectedImage'` symbol.

This is my activity:

```
private void openFileChooserOne() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = 1200;
        height = (int)(width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = 1200;
        width = (int)(height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
        data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        try {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            selectedImage = getResizedBitmap(selectedImage, 1200);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void uploadFile() {
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String userID = user.getUid();
    if (mImageUri != null && mImageMedicalUri != null) {
        StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(userID).child("photo.jpg");
        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(selectedImage)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > () {
                //...
            })
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to figure out if I'm sending a string and this is causing the error, or anything else I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `selectedImage` variable in the `uploadFile()` method body you need to make `selectedImage` be a **field** of your Activity class, like that:

```
    private Bitmap selectedImage; 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
            data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            try {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                selectedImage = getResizedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream), 1200);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadFile() {
        //selectedImage now resolved
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it says, `putFile(android.net.Uri) in StorageReference cannot be applied to (android.graphics.Bitmap)`

Comment: @Hijibiji putFile(android.net.Uri) in StorageReference cannot be applied to (android.graphics.Bitmap) - it is the different issue and does not link to your current question. You should create a new question and show the code where you are trying to store the Bitmap.